# Show More Details Option in Windows Vista Progress Dialog

Tags: winapi, dialog, progressdialog, shell32

I use the [IProgressDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775248(v=vs.85).aspx) interface in order to create a ProgressDialog with Windows-Vista style like this:

[image: My ProgressDialog]

Dialogs that are shown while copying, pasting and moving files in Windows Explorer usually offer an additional button "More Details" that provides further information about the current progress.

[image: ProgressDialogs in Windows]

Is there any possibility to display and work with this button regarding the IProgressDialog interface?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second screenshot is screenshot of [IOperationsProgressDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog. IProgressDialog does not have feature you want.

Comment: A [Task Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471.aspx) also supports a progress bar and a Details pane.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but then you'd have to implement all the functionality when you could just use  IOperationsProgressDialog which seems pointless

Comment: Thank you, Denis Anisimov. Your answer exactly meets my requirements.