# How to use IOperationsProgressDialog in C#

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to use the [`IOperationsProgressDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775368(v=vs.85).aspx) component in my Windows Forms desktop application, but so far without success. I declared the following COM import types in C#...

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4")]
internal class ProgressDialog
{
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("0C9FB851-E5C9-43EB-A370-F0677B13874C")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IOperationsProgressDialog
{
    ...
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("EBBC7C04-315E-11d2-B62F-006097DF5BD4")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IProgressDialog
{
    ...
}
```

Class- and interface-id´s are taken from `shlobj.h` and `shobjidl.h` header files from the Windows 10 SDK; so I assume they are correct. The following code allows me to create, show and update an `IProgressDialog`, but...

```
private IProgressDialog dialog;

public void Show(
    IWin32Window owner,
    string title,
    string cancelMessage)
{
    var dialog = (IProgressDialog)(new ProgressDialog());

    dialog.SetTitle(title);
    dialog.SetCancelMsg(cancelMessage, IntPtr.Zero);

    uint dwFlags = PROGDLG_NORMAL | PROGDLG_AUTOTIME;
    int hr = dialog.StartProgressDialog(owner.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, dwFlags, IntPtr.Zero);

    this.dialog = dialog;
}

public void SetProgress(ulong value, ulong total)
{
    this.dialog?.SetProgress64(value, total);
}
```

...it just don´t work with the `IOperationsProgressDialog`, which has (as I assume) the same `CLSID`. I´d like to use the `IOperationsProgressDialog` component instead of `IProgressDialog` since it allows the user to show more detailed information about the running operation.

```
private IOperationsProgressDialog dialog;

public void Show(
    IWin32Window owner)
{
    var dialog = (IOperationsProgressDialog)(new ProgressDialog());

    int hr = dialog.StartProgressDialog(owner.Handle, PROGDLG_NORMAL);

    this.dialog = dialog;
}

public void SetProgress(ulong value, ulong total)
{
    this.dialog?.UpdateProgress(0, 0, value, total, 0, 0);
}
```

The call to `StartProgressDialog` seems to work fine (the method returns `S_OK`), but the dialog never get´s shown and subsequent calls to other methods defined by the `IOperationsProgressDialog` interface result in an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: You followed this: *The progress dialog should be created on a separate thread*, right?

Comment: The creation of the `IProgressDialog` happens on the application´s main thread, but the progress is updated by a separate thread. Not sure if I can create the dialog on a separate thread, if I want make it modal... The documentation says "The progress dialog should be created on a separate thread than the file operation on which the dialog is reporting."

Comment: IOperationsProgressDialog was meant to be implemented by your own code, you use it to call IFileOperation.SetProgressDialog().  Allows you to replace, say, the pretty progress graph on the file copy dialog.  The StartProgressDialog() method is supposed to be called by whatever coclass implements the IFileOperation, after it has created the dialog window.  Why the cast from ProgressDialog works at all is hard to guess, it isn't documented at all.  I very much doubt this is supposed to work.

Comment: @HansPassant Aha... but what about this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506948/show-more-details-option-in-windows-vista-progress-dialog

Comment: The second screenshot is the file copy dialog I mentioned.  It starts life from CLSID_FileOperation, not CLSID_ProgressDialog.